# What is the kernel of $i_*:H_1(\partial M)=H_1(T^2)\rightarrow H_1(M)$ for $M$ a 3-manifold with torus boundary and $i$ the inclusion?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

It can be shown by a calculation using the Mayer-Vietoris sequence that for $M$ a knot complement in $S^3$, the map on first homology group induced by inclusion $i_*:H_1(\partial M) \rightarrow H_1(M)$ always satisfies $\ker i_*=\mathbb {Z}=\langle\lambda\rangle,$ where $\lambda$ is called the preferred longitude.

How about a general 3 manifolds with torus boundary? Is the kernel of the map $i_*:H_1(\partial M)\rightarrow H_1(M)$ always $\mathbb{Z}?$

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the Lemma 3.5 in Hatcher's notes on basic 3-manifold topology says that it is true under coefficient $\mathbb{Q}$.